# Pulumi SDK SQL deletion protection not working

Tags: go, pulumi

I have provisioned SQL (PostrgresSQL) on GCP cloud using Pulumi SDK (Go).
I have set deletionProtection as true - but checking GCP console I can see the SQL is not protected. I was able to delete the instance using console by that breaking Pulumi state.

```
+ gcp:sql/databaseInstance:DatabaseInstance: (create)
            [urn=urn:pulumi:us-east4-dev-google-cloud-sql-example::google-cloud-sql-example::gcp:myproject/sql:Database$gcp:sql/databaseInstance:DatabaseInstance::google-cloud-sql]
            databaseVersion   : "POSTGRES_12"
            deletionProtection: true
            name              : "google-cloud-sql-0b96b6d"
            project           : "my-project"
            region            : "us-east4"
            settings          : {
                availabilityType   : "REGIONAL"
                backupConfiguration: {
                    enabled                   : false
                    pointInTimeRecoveryEnabled: false
                }
                databaseFlags      : [
                    [0]: {
                        name      : "auto_explain.log_analyze"
                        value     : "on"
                    }
                    [1]: {
                        name      : "max_connections"
                        value     : "800"
                    }
                ]
                diskAutoresize     : true
                diskAutoresizeLimit: 0
                diskSize           : 200
                diskType           : "PD_SSD"
                insightsConfig     : {
                    queryInsightsEnabled: false
                    queryStringLength   : 1024
                }
                ipConfiguration    : {
                    ipv4Enabled   : false
                    privateNetwork: "projects/my-project/global/networks/dev-vpc"
                }
                pricingPlan        : "PER_USE"
                tier               : "db-custom-32-122880"
                userLabels         : {
                    compliance : "cisl1"
                    criticality: "2"
                    environment: "dev"
                    monitored  : "true"
                    name       : "myusername"
                    owner      : "devops_backend"
                    persistence: "persistent"
                    purpose    : "pulumi-common-google-cloud-sql-example"
                }
            }
```

Comment: When trying to delete using Pulumi a protected SQL instance I get this error message:

```bash
gcp:sql:DatabaseInstance (google-cloud-sql):
    error: deleting urn:pulumi:us-east4-dev-google-cloud-sql-example::google-cloud-sql-example::gcp:sentinelone/sql:Database$gcp:sql/databaseInstance:DatabaseInstance::google-cloud-sql: 1 error occurred:
     * Error, failed to delete instance because deletion_protection is set to true. Set it to false to proceed with instance deletion
```

Answer (score 0):

The deletion protection setting in GCP is configured by another property in the [DatabaseInstanceSettings](https://www.pulumi.com/registry/packages/gcp/api-docs/sql/databaseinstance/#databaseinstancesettings) object

You will need to update your settings like this:

```
databaseVersion   : "POSTGRES_12"
            deletionProtection: true
            name              : "google-cloud-sql-0b96b6d"
            project           : "my-project"
            region            : "us-east4"
            settings          : {
                availabilityType   : "REGIONAL"
                deletionProtectionEnabled: true
```